# What is the best way to pass a promise between screens and awaiting for result, reducing wait times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

My intention is to reduce wait time for users when they transition to a screen which requires data from the API.

Currently it's something like this, where `fetchSomeData` returns a promise:

```
// Screen 1
this.navigateToScreenTwo()

// Screen 2
async componentDidMount(){
  try {
    const data = await fetchSomeData()
    this.setState({ data })
  } catch(e){}
}
```

What I want to do is start the promise, pass it through to the next screen in the navigation state, and then await its result in the next screen. Because the screen transition takes 300ms, this is enough time to get a result from the API, making the transition and data load seamless.

**Is it good practice to do something like this? If not, what would be the best way to do it?**

```
// Screen 1
const dataPromise = fetchSomeData() // purposely without await
this.navigateToScreenTwo({ dataPromise }) // pass promise in navigation

// Screen 2
async componentDidMount(){
  try {
    const data = await this.navigation.dataPromise // the promise from navigation state
    this.setState({ data })
  } catch(e){}
}
```

Of lesser importance: **should there be a try/catch in Screen 1 where the promise is first returned?**

Comment: Are "screens" different *pages*? That is, is the global environment torn down and recreated when you move from "Screen 1" to "Screen 2"?

Comment: *"should there be a try/catch in Screen 1 where the promise is first returned"* Ask **one** question per question, not two. Addressing this second one: One of the fundamental rules of promises is: Either handle errors, or pass the promise onto something else (which handles errors, or passes the promise onto...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I was speaking in a mobile context mainly, but this equally applies to web. So in web this would be a react-router transition, for example.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) the component tree and handle the async call in a parent?

Comment: @krisaoe For example in react-router, I'm transitioning between screens inside a Switch component that is inside the Router, there is currently no state held at that level as its more or less the app's highest context. In an application with 100+ pages, there would have to be a very generalised solution for this like redux etc.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably work, as long as you've verified that there are no problems with whatever the implementation of `navigateToScreenTwo` is, and as long as it's in a simple enough app.

But this is not a very maintainable strategy, and doesn't follow normal React patterns. Rather than this, I would use a state management system that works across components, such as React Context, Mobx, Redux, or any of a multitude of other options. The async job would end by updating the application state, and would not need to be passed around at all.

A try/catch in screen 1 would only catch synchronous errors, not promise rejections. It's unlikely to be necessary in most cases but it depends on whether `fetchSomeData` might throw an error synchronously (before returning the promise).

Comment: *"A try/catch in screen 1 would only catch synchronous errors, not promise rejections."* That isn't true if it's in an `async` function. We don't have any context for the call in the "Screen 1" code...

Comment: We know that it is being purposefully called without the `await` keyword, so only synchronous errors would be handled if it was wrapped in a try/catch. It doesn't matter in this case if the function on screen 1 is marked as async, it only matters that it's not using the `await` keyword.

Comment: There is a comment on that line stating "purposely without await", I'm not reading into anything :)

Comment: Ha! There is that, I was looking at the first code block. I would still clarify that part of the answer. Not like it would take much time.